# Why signtool.exe don't support /as option while dual sign SHA2 and SHA1

Tags: signtool

I got error about /as option when dual sign SHA2 and SHA1

```
signtool sign /v /n "name" /sha1 "sha1 hash" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll my.exe
signtool sign /v /n "name" /sha1 "sha1 hash for sha256" /as /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.geotrust.com/tsa /td sha256 my.exe
```

> SignTool Error: Invalid option: /as

I guess if my signtool.exe version is not support /as option? I used signtool.exe version is 6.1.7600.16385 BTY, i can sign SHA2 successfully without /as option.

Comment: BTY,I using signtool.exe both in my windows 7 or windows server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can dual sign files successful while i use the higher version 6.2.9200.20527 of signtool. The signtool is belong to windows sdk 8 https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-8-sdk. I guess that the more higher version above of windows 8 sdk also can support /as option too.

Comment: Are you saying that you managed to dual sign (SHA1+SHA256) a file under Windows 7? With SHA256 timestamp? If yes, please provide your full command.

Comment: i've manage to double sign my files under windows 7 professional using two commands :

"V:\Bin\signtool.exe"  sign /f "V:\instalador\YourSoftware-code-sign.pfx" /p "123456" /d "YourSoftware  Your Company" /du "https://YourSoftware.com.br/" /fd sha1 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/?td=sha1 /td sha1 "C:\exe\YourSoftware.exe"
 ------ 
"V:\Bin\signtool.exe"  sign /f "V:\instalador\YourSoftware-code-sign.pfx" /p "123456" /d "YourSoftware Your Company" /du "https://YourSoftware.com.br/" /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/?td=sha256 /td sha256 /as "C:\exe\YourSoftware.exe"

Answer (score 0):

You need Windows 8/10, it's impossible at least for now under Windows 7, which is really strange. Even if you will use newer signtool binaries under Windows 7 (for example from SDK 10) still it will be not possible to use /as switch.

Comment: This is not correct. I am at this moment doing a dual sign on a Windows 7 machine and it works fine. The key is to use a newer version of signtool that supports dual signing. In my case I installed the Windows 8.1 SDK  on my Windows 7 machine. The SDK  includes a version of signtool that supports dual signing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the actual reason for the issue is this: signtool.exe is linked with mssign32.dll and wintrust.dll. These dlls are found under %WinDir%\system32 and on Windows 7 don't seem to support dual signing. WinSDK 8.x comes with its own versions of these dlls in the same folder as the signtool.exe. Here dual signing works! With older SDK versions it doesn't. I just installed the WinSDK 10 on my Windows 7 and again it does no longer work here as this SDK does no longer come with its own versions of the dlls mentioned above. I guess this is why others think it works under Windows 8.x and higher only as here the mssign32.dll is newer...